# Find pairs $(a,b,c,d)$

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Given that $\gcd(am + b, cm + d) = 2019$ for every positive integer m, find all possible values of $|ad-bc|$ with $(a,b,c,d) \in\ \mathbb{Z}_+ $

How can I solve this problem? I am very new to number theory and don't understand how to manipulate it to get a solution.

I considered making the equation into a Diophantine equation but don't know how to find the constant values of the Diophantine.

Any answer is appreciated.

Thank you for your patience!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Please update your question to indicate what you've tried so far, including possibly other context such as where this question comes from. Note I've already written, posted & deleted an answer. If you show what you've done, and especially what you had a problem with, I can possibly update my answer to address those issue(s) before I undelete it.

Comment: Hi, John. I considered making the equation into a Diophantine equation and then solving for the constant values but I don't understand how to acquire those constant values of the Diophantine.

Comment: @DarinClark Thanks for responding. I added an initial note to my answer to address what you considered before undeleting my answer. Note there's already one vote to close your question due to missing context. Please also update your question text to state what you just wrote to help avoid getting more votes to close. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your stated condition, as you said in your question, you can create $2$ Diophantine equations. However, you don't need to directly solve for the constant values as the question only asks for what $|ad - bc|$ can be. Instead, note $\gcd(am+b,cm+d) = 2019$ means you have for every positive integer $m$ that

$$am + b = 2019e \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

$$cm + d = 2019f \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

for some integers $e$ and $f$, with $\gcd(e,f) = 1$. Multiply \eqref{eq1A} by $d$ and subtract \eqref{eq2A} multiplied by $b$ to get

$$(ad - bc)m = 2019(de - bf) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Next, let

$$\gcd(b,d) = g, \; b = gh, \; d = gi, \; \gcd(h,i) = 1 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Thus, \eqref{eq3A} then becomes

$$(ad - bc)m = 2019(g)(ie - hf) \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Note that $ie - hf$, due to the variables involved between the $2$ terms not having any common factors, can be basically any integer. However, you do have that $2019(g)$ must divide $(ad - bc)m$. Since this has to be true for *all* positive integers $m$, including those which have no common factors with $2019(g)$, it can *only* always happen if

$$2019(g) \mid |ad - bc| \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Next, multiply \eqref{eq1A} by $c$ and subtract \eqref{eq2A} multiplied by $a$ to get

$$cb - ad = 2019(ce - af) \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

Let

$$\gcd(a,c) = j, \; a = jk, \; c = jn, \; \gcd(k,n) = 1 \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

Thus, \eqref{eq7A} becomes

$$cb - ad = 2019(j)(ne - kf) \tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$

As before, this means

$$2019(j) \mid |ad - bc| \tag{10}\label{eq10A}$$

If you let

$$q = \text{lcm}(g,j) \tag{11}\label{eq11A}$$

Then combining \eqref{eq6A} and \eqref{eq10A}, you get overall that $|ad - bc|$ must be a non-negative integral multiple of $2019(q)$.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know of any places where I can practice Number Theory questions like these?

Comment: @DarinClark You're welcome. As for places to practice number theory questions similar to yours, there are many here at Math SE. Some good tags to check on are elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem, etc. Also, there are various good books & sites on the Web you can use. However, I don't have any particular suggestions about that for you. Assuming you're in school, I suggest you ask your teacher and/or class-mates about this.